# MIP SDK file handler prints "MIP Error: XPath returned no results" after upgrading to 1.9

Tags: microsoft-information-protection, azure-information-protection, mip-sdk

File handler was throwing error for some png file so I updated the SDK to 1.9.90 from 1.8.102.

Now it works fine but printing error for CreateFileHandlerAsync() method saying " MIP Error: XPath returned no results (`anonymous-namespace'::GetXmlNodesFromPath:src\protection\rest_clients\license_parser.cpp:209"

Answer (score 0):

This will likely require investigation by engineering. I’d recommend opening a support case so we can get all of the required logs. Can you reproduce the error on other files, or newly protected files?